# What key is this hash tag note?

Tags: key-signatures, accidentals

[image]

In the treble clef line , what key is the hash tag note?

I know it’s a black key but can’t remember which .

Comment: Do you remember, which note you would press if there was no sharp ("_hash tag_")? The sharp raises the note by a semitone. Have a look: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature)

Answer (score 2):

This hashtag is what we call a "sharp." It raises the pitch by one half step.

I'm assuming you mean the sharp in the *bass* clef. (Based on the music, it's hard for me to imagine these both being in treble clef.)

Since the written note is F, you'll move it up one half step to the nearest black key to make it F♯. If you're still having trouble finding this key, look for the group of three black keys; it will be the one on the far left.

If the left hand is in fact in treble clef, this pitch will be a D♯, which is the right-most black key in the grouping of two black keys.

Comment: (I thought for certain this was a duplicate, but I can't find a clear question/answer for this. I apologize if there is a clear duplicate that I missed.)

Comment: Does it look weird to you - there's no note to be sung with the word 'peace'. I've heard of peace and quiet, maybe this takes it further?

Comment: @Tim: I think the tune goes mifa mi re do re so. The note of peace is in the bass clef. It seems to be an arrangement for "easy piano" (beginners)

Comment: Bach would surely write a fuge to the theme hashtag mi too ...